# Store multiple row table into array to allow for user updates

Tags: php, mysql

I have struggled with this concept for a while and am hoping someone can help, please. I can query database records if all values are stored in one row. The challenge I have is when the quantity values are stored on multiple rows but with a common key (e.g. order_id). I want to store into an array and then assign each value to an on-screen variable to allow user updates so that I can update the table again.

For example, if the table looks as follows:

```
    id  line    part    qty
    --  ----    ----    ---
    1   1       63      2
    1   2       104     3
    1   3       54      2
    1   4       50      1
```

I have not had success with the following where I establish the number of rows and then try to build a foreach loop to capture the data:

```
    $sql = 'SELECT *, COUNT(*) as $count FROM Order_Items where order_id = ?';
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    for ($x = 0; $x <= $count; $x++ {
       $var($x) = $data['qty'];
    }
```

If I can properly separate the values into an array and then reference them somehow, then I could do the following and get them displayed and easily update back to the database:

```
$var_1  = $data['63'];  // part_id = 63
$var_2  = $data['104']; // part_id = 104
$var_3  = $data['54'];  // part_id = 54
$var_4  = $data['50'];  // part_id = 50
```

Comment: what's this `$sql = 'SELECT *, COUNT(*) as $count FROM Order_Items where order_id = ?';` about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT *, COUNT(*) as $count FROM Order_Items where order_id = ?';
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($id));
$data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

for ($x = 0; $x <= $count; $x++ {
   $var($x) = $data['qty'];
}
```

To something that makes sense like this

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Order_Items where order_id = ?';
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($id));
while(false !== ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){
    echo $row['qty'];
};
```

**UPDATE**

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Order_Items where order_id = ?';
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($id));
$array = [];
while(false !== ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){
    $array['line_'.$row['line']] = $row;
};
```

**UPDATE**

The additional code that answers what I was looking for is as follows. Your answer was key to my understanding it all:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Order_Items where order_id = ?';
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($id));
$array = [];
while(false !== ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){
    $qty['line_'.$row['line']] = $row['qty'];
};

$var_54 = $qty['line_54'];
$var_63 = $qty['line_63'];
```

Comment: thank you. Yes, I know how to print_r or echo values onto the screen. The challenge is to capture them into an array so that I can allow the user to update and then allow me to update the table again, please

Comment: That's not really a challenge.

Comment: Can I reference the array for $row['part'] instead of $row['line']? How do I now push the array into my specific variables that correspond to the part?

Comment: You can change that to what you want, I have it as `line_{n}` where `{n}` is the line so  `line_1`,`line_2` etc...  Integer keys in PHP can be a bit tricky depending on what you do to them.  For example json_encoding them isn't that good of an idea if you wan't to keep the data they contain. So I try to avoid int keys, just by habit.

Comment: If you don't know how arrays work, I suggest viewing some tutorials on PHP, because it's more help then I can give in the format of this site.  They can also explain it in more detail and help you learn it where here it is generally answering a specific problem.